# Ошибка Argument of type '{ item: string; id: number; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(reason: any) => PromiseLike<never>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook

Я создаю имитатор поиска на сервере. Хочу что-бы когда промис возвращал reject отлавливать ошибку с помощью catch и вызывать функцию поиска на клиенте. Пытаюсь в catch вызвать функцию search (функция поиска на клиенте), однако появляется ошибка. Из-за чего она выходит и как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну дак вам ведь написали, что в catch должна быть функция, а не массив который вы возвращаете из функции `search`. Напишите `.catch((reason) => console.log('after error', reason))` увидите ошибку. Ну или напишите в теле этой функции всё что вам нужно вместо console.log.

Comment: Нашел ошибку. Спасибо за совет.